# Beautiful Soup not importing

Tags: python, macos, beautifulsoup

I'm on OSX and i've previously installed bs4 in terminal. 
So trying to install it again i get:

```
    $ pip install beautifulsoup4

    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py2.7.egg
```

When i try importing bs4 i get this error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):   
     File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>    
     import bs4    
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 468    
     print soup.prettify()    
              ^    
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do i fix this? The bs4 file originally downloaded into my python2.7 file so i copied and pasted it into a folder that's on my python path. I'm pretty sure this was the wrong thing to do, but what should i do now to get it properly working? I've looked at other similar questions on here (which admittedly there are many) but I haven't found a solution that has worked yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Getting a print without brackets in `Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5` would be a problem. Your copy and paste operation between Python versions would not seem to have been a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 that print statement should have parentheses `print(soup.prettify())`, I am not sure why it is not in your case, it seems you have `bs4` from python 2 version. Try force install beautiful soup again `$ pip install --ignore-installed beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: I got a permission denied error trying that. Any way i can overcome that?

Comment: Install as admin, you should use `$ sudo pip install --ignore-installed beautifulsoup4`

Comment: I've just done that but am still getting the parentheses errors from what I guess are the original files. It's installed it in the 2.7 directory again. Should i just completely delete the 2.7? I only downloaded python recently so not sure why it's even there.

Comment: Oh, wait I see that pip is for Python 2 installation. You should use `pip3` which should install packages for Python 3. Or otherwise, use bs4 with Python 2 instead.

Comment: That worked, thanks for all you help. Will remember to do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

```
 print (soup.prettify())
```

python 3 uses print() as a function.

i.e.

```
print ("hello world")
```

also can do like

```
print("hello world",end="")
```

so that there is no new line

There might also be a lot of errors from version 2 package migrating to version 3 as a couple of things have changed, I am able to run bs4 though but i got it on python 3.

Comment: This fixed that one error message, but now I have the same in one of the other files. Is there a way to correctly reinstall bs4 so i don't have to manually change all these missing parentheses?

Comment: I was using Netbeans which I just click on the package, So it depends on your platform. Those parenthesis are from the different Python versions, Python 3 uses parenthesis as it has changed.